# HTML-esque alternatives to Pug

Tags: html, node.js

We are looking to replace [Pug](https://pugjs.org) as our template engine (we have a NodeJS server) with something that has **syntax closer to actual HTML**.

Ideally the template engine should *at least* have:

- Support for partials.
- Support for conditions, i.e: if/else expressions.
- Support for passing variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) seems to fit the bill perfectly.